# Cómo borrar círculos

Tags: java, android

Estoy creando un juego donde se crean círculos de diferentes tamaños y colores cada cierto tiempo. El problema es que quiero eliminar todos los círculos de un color al tocar un botón.

Por ejemplo tengo el botón rojo y tiene que eliminar todos los círculos de color rojo, pero no logro hacerlo.

¿Alguno tiene alguna idea para orientarme?

Clase Juego:

```
public class Juego extends SurfaceView{

    private Paint paint;
    int i = 0;
    Bolitas bolitas;

    private List<Bolitas> sprites = new ArrayList<Bolitas>();

    public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        sumarBolas();
        sprites = new ArrayList<>();

        bolitas = new Bolitas(this);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);

        for (Bolitas bolas : sprites) {
            bolas.onDraw(canvas);
        }

        invalidate();

    }

    private Bolitas createSprite() {
        return new Bolitas(this);
    }

    public void sumarBolas(){
        new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                if (i<5){
                    sprites.add(createSprite());
                    i++;
                    sumarBolas();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Clase Bolitas:

```
public class Bolitas {

    int x, y, radio, color, donde_aparece, velocidadX=5, velocidadY=5;
    Juego juego;
    Paint paint;
    boolean una_vez = true;

    public Bolitas(Juego juego){

        this.juego = juego;

        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            if (una_vez == true) {
                Random random = new Random();
                color = random.nextInt(4);
                radio = random.nextInt(70) + 30;
                donde_aparece = random.nextInt(4);

                if (donde_aparece == 0) {
                    x = random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth());
                    y = radio;
                } else if (donde_aparece == 1) {
                    x = random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth());
                    y = canvas.getHeight() - radio;
                } else if (donde_aparece == 2) {
                    y = random.nextInt(canvas.getHeight());
                    x = radio;
                } else if (donde_aparece == 3) {
                    y = random.nextInt(canvas.getHeight());
                    x = canvas.getWidth() - radio;
                }
                una_vez = false;
            }

            if (color == 0) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);
            } else if (color == 1) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);
            } else if (color == 2) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);
            } else if (color == 3) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);
            }

            if (x >= canvas.getWidth() - radio) {
                velocidadX = -5;
            }
            if (x <= radio) {
                velocidadX = 5;
            }
            if (y >= canvas.getHeight() - radio) {
                velocidadY = -5;
            }
            if (y <= radio) {
                velocidadY = 5;
            }

            x = x + velocidadX;
            y = y + velocidadY;
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button rojo;
    private Juego juego;
    Bolitas bolitas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rojo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rojo);
        juego = (Juego) findViewById(R.id.customView);
        bolitas = new Bolitas(juego);
    }

    public void rojo(View view){

    }
}
```